# How can i access fedora15 desktop with remote desktop from another fedora15

Tags: remote-desktop, rdesktop, fedora

My current desktop is Fedora15. I need to access my desktop from another fedora15 desktop using remotedesktop viewer. Please help on this

Answer (score 1):

The Fedora project has some [documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User_Guide_-_Sharing_Your_Desktop) that can help you out.

It boils down to installing a VNC server on the desktop you wish to view, and a VNC viewer on the desktop you wish to view it from. Fedora makes this easy with the "Desktop sharing" tool.

If you need to access a machine over the internet, make sure the necessary ports are open in the firewall, both on the Fedora box and on the router (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Under the System pull down in Gnome, launch the Remote Desktop App, System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop. From here check the allow other users to view your desktop. Also set the security and notification sections accordingly.

[image: Remote Desktop Dialog]

Once you're setup your Fedora system so that it will accept remote connections you can use a remote desktop client such as Vinagre, again a Gnome app, from the Applications pull down, Applications -> Internet -> Remote Desktop Viewer. Once this application comes up you'll need to open a connection to a remote server.

[image: Remote Desktop Viewer]

In the connection dialog select VNC for the connection protocol and put either the remote servers name or ip address and click connect.

[image]